# How are the various similar simd_ functions different from each other?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, scenekit, simd

In typical Apple fashion, there's no documentation (and what little there borders on trolling). For example, what is [`simd_precise_normalize(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/2896739-simd_precise_normalize?changes=_7)? You’d be forgiven for thinking it was a slower, more precise normalization than `simd_fast_normalize(_:)`. But then why does `simd_normalize(_:)` exist?

Why is there `simd_cross(simd_float3, simd_float3)` and `cross(SIMD3<Float>, SIMD3<Float>)` when `typealias simd_float3 = SIMD3<Float>`?

And what about the Swift operator overloads on `simd_float3`?

I've written a bug to Apple about it, but does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

> But then why does simd_normalize(_:) exist?

[This comment](https://github.com/xybp888/iOS-SDKs/blob/master/iPhoneOS13.0.sdk/usr/include/simd/geometry.h#L53-L64) explains it. `simd_normalize` is equivalent to `simd_precise_normalize` unless you are compiling with `-ffast-math` specified, in which case it is equivalent to `simd_fast_normalize`. I never used swift only objective-c, but it’s possible there’s equivalent option somewhere in compiler switches or xcode project settings.

> Why is there simd_cross(simd_float3, simd_float3) and cross(SIMD3, SIMD3)

I think they are equivalent. Note that comments in the header discuss both C-style API like `simd_cross(x,y)` and C++ API `simd::cross(x,y)`. It could be that in Swift both are available for some of these functions.